# Regex between, from the last to specific end

Tags: c#, regex

Today my wish is to take text form the string. 
This string must be, between **last slash** and **.partX.rar** or **.rar**

First I tried to find edge's end of the word and then the beginning. After I get that two elements I merged them but I got empty results.

String:

```
http://hosting.xyz/1234/15-game.part4.rar.html

http://hosting.xyz/1234/16-game.rar.html
```

Regex:

Begin:`(([^/]*)$)` -  start from last `/`

End:`(.*(?=.part[0-9]+.rar|.rar))` stop before `.partX.rar` or `.rar`

As you see, if I merge that codes I won't get any result.
What is more, "end" select me only .partX instead of .partX.rar

All what I want is:
`15-game.part4.rar` and `16-game.rar`

---

What i tried:

```
(([^/]*)$)(.*(?=.part[0-9]+.rar|.rar))

(([^/]*)$)

(.*(?=.part[0-9]+.rar|.rar))
```

I tried also

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

but I do not know how select symbols.. This could be the easiest way. But this select only letters and numbers, not `-` or `_`.
If I could select symbols..

Comment: He posted (at least) something that he tried.

Comment: as I said `(([^/]*)$)(.*(?=.part[0-9]+.rar|.rar))` this I tried, I tried also `(([^/]*)$)` and `(.*(?=.part[0-9]+.rar|.rar))`, I tried also `/[a-zA-Z0-9]+` but I do not know how select symbols.. This could be the easiest way. But this select only letters and numbers, not `-` - do  you know how to select till `.` dot?

Comment: What language are you working within? Java/Javascript/C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a C# coder so can't write full code here but I think you'll need support of `negative lookahead` here like this:

```
new Regex("/(?!.*/)(.+?)\.html$");
```

Matched Group # 1 will have your string i.e. `"16-game.rar"` OR `"15-game.part4.rar"`

Comment: could I ask you to explain me this regex command, I would appreciate for this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure I will try. This regex basically has a negative lookahead `/(?!.*/)` which means match a `/` which is **NOT followed** by some text and another `/`. This basically makes sure that we **match only last /**. Rest is straight forward where `(.+?)\.html` matches a text that has `.html` in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing could be simpler! :-)

Use this:

```
new Regex("^.*\/(.*)\.html$")
```

You'll find your filename in the first captured group (don't have a c# compiler at hand, so can't give you working sample, but you have a working regex now! :-) )

See a demo here: http://rubular.com/r/UxFNtJenyF

Comment: Ah. C# guy :-) Then put this into a Regex constructor: `^.*\/(.*)$`. Leading and trailing slashes are part of regex literal in some languages.

Comment: Yeah, I see but doesn't on C#, and `.html` is no need.
C# gives me all source of link.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a regex for this as you can merely split the url on `/` and then grab the part of the file name that you need.  Since you didn't mention a language, here's an implementation in Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str1="http://hosting.xyz/1234/15-game.part4.rar.html";

my $str2="http://hosting.xyz/1234/16-game.rar.html";

my $file1=(split(/\//,$str1))[-1]; #last element of the resulting array from splitting on slash

my $file2=(split(/\//,$str2))[-1];

foreach($file1,$file2)
{
  s/\.html$//; #for each file name, if it ends in ".html", get rid of that ending.
  print "$_\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
15-game.part4.rar
16-game.rar
```

Comment: He's using c#, apparently :-)

Comment: Yes, sorry forget about code language. I though that regex is universal. Btw. your code helped me a lot. I forgot about rule **KISS**! :) However it is not regex, doh! :P

Answer (score 0):

Use two regexes:

- start to substitute `.*/` with nothing;
- then substitute `\.html` with nothing.

Job done!