# Regex - Replace beginning from last > to a tag

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

Before all: My english is not that good, so... I'd like to ask for apologizes if you guys can't understand me :)

So, this is what I'm looking for:
I'm being using a Wordpress plugin to generate XML (WP ALL EXPORT). Good.

Now, I need to open a file and edit some stuffs. I started with:

```
$data = file_get_contents("1439828483.xml");
```

And now I'm working using str_replace and preg_replace to update the lines I need.

I have two XML tag like these:

```
<cidade><![CDATA[sao-paulo>santo-andre]]></cidade>
<bairro><![CDATA[sao-paulo>santo-andre]]></bairro>
```

You see the content is the same... but it's because I have one ">" character splitting 2 stuff.

In the `<cidade></cidade>` tag I need to keep only what is before ">".
In the `<bairro></bairro>` tag I need to keep only what is after ">".

For the second problem, I fixed using this:

```
$data = preg_replace('#(<bairro>).*?(>)#', '$1$2', $data);
$data = str_replace('<bairro>>', "<bairro><![CDATA[",$data);
```

The result is:

```
<bairro><![CDATA[santo-andre]]></bairro>
```

OK, I have the content but it still have hyphens (dashes) and now I'm not able to fix it (No idea how to). What I really need is:

```
<bairro><![CDATA[santo andre]]></bairro>
```

And of course, for the tag `<cidade></cidade>` I would need to have:

```
<cidade><![CDATA[sao paulo]]></cidade>
```

Before posting here, I found this topic:
[Regex between, from the last to specific end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732655/regex-between-from-the-last-to-specific-end)

But I tried to edit some parts of anubhava and Jack Maney answers but I failed :(

As I'm using preg_replace and str_replace I don't know if there is some limitations for regex strings.

Thanks and I hope you guys can understand me :D

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to parse XML with regex. You might be able to get away with it for XML this simple, but it's [usually not a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/399649). It looks like [PHP already has an XML parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php), so you might find that more useful.

Comment: Probably it's true... but since I could fix 90% of it using this technique, I thought I could be able to finish it.... I mean.... this is the last problem :P

And... this seems to be able to be fixed. It's only a case of regex and preg_replace. Not a big deal for people that know how those 2 stuff work (not my case ^^).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it (and replaces your own fix):

```
$data = preg_replace('#(<bairro><!\[CDATA\[)[^>]*?>([^>]*?><)#', '$1$2', $data);
while(preg_match('#(<bairro>[^->]*?)-([^->]*?-)*([^->]*?'.'>)#', $data)) {
    $data = preg_replace('#(<bairro>[^->]*?)-(([^->]*?-)*)([^->]*?'.'>)#', '$1 $2$4', $data);
}
$data = preg_replace('#(<cidade><!\[CDATA\[[^>]*?)>[^>]*?(\]\]><)#', '$1$2', $data);
while(preg_match('#(<cidade>[^->]*?)-([^->]*?-)*([^->]*?'.'>)#', $data)) {
    $data = preg_replace('#(<cidade>[^->]*?)-(([^->]*?-)*)([^->]*?'.'>)#', '$1 $2$4', $data);
}
```

Comment: Man, you're the best :P

But it didn't remove the dashes from the first tag.

Comment: You mean the hyphen inside of cidade? It removes it when there is one hyphen. Do you have another example?

Comment: Oh yeah! It has more than one hyphen.
rio-de-janeiro
sao-jose-do-campo-grande

It can have a lot of hyphens.

Even the bairro tag can have. Is there a solution to remove ALL hyphens?

Answer (score 0):

Let me just point out that [parsing XML with regex is often a bad idea,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/399649) partly for reasons you're discovering. However, if all you want to do is replace hyphens with spaces, just do this:

```
$data = str_replace_all('-', " ", $data);
```

This will replace ALL the hyphens in your input, of course, so make sure you know what's in there.

Comment: But this is a XML with lots of information.
If I replace ALL hyphens, I will destroy good info that need this "-".

I need to replace only dashes from a selected tag.